# Encoding random variables with binary strings

Tags: information-theory

It is said that a random variable $X$ with a uniform distribution over 4 outcomes needs a binary string of 2 bits to encode (eg, Cover & Thomas 2nd Ed., p.5; and it corresponds to the *entropy* of $X$, the fundamental lower bound in the length of the encoding string). But I am wondering what prevents us from using the following encoding scheme which uses only 1.5 bits on average:

```
String '0' for the first outcome
String '1' for the second outcome
String '00' for the third outcome
String '01' for the fourth outcome
```

Thanks!

Comment: The entropy has nothing to do with the mode of representation: it's a function of the *probabilities.*  Those remain equal to $1/4$ each, regardless of how you name the outcomes, and the entropy therefore remains constant at $-\log_2(1/4)=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice try, but the '0' for the first outcome is a prefix for the third and fourth outcomes.  How would you decode the sequence 0010100? Is it 1121211, or 3134, or 1443, or what? The problem arises because of DELIMITERS, and once you include them, the average number of bits increases.

And did you mean that H(X) = lg(4) = 2 was the UPPER bound?

Comment: Excellent - thank you. I did mean lower bound: $H(X)$ is the lower bound on the average number of bits required to represent it, no?